# Get Access to unlock OSX Harddrive

Tags: macos, hard-drive

A user is locked out and we have some passwords to try for his Harddrive so we can unlock single user mode however we can't seem to find a way to get to that stage.

Recovery mode works but we need to unlock the HDD as there are drives showing up with accounts so we can't use the password reset via terminal either.

Thanks

Macbook
Mojave

Comment: We don't have enough information to start from - precisely which Mac, which OS, is FileVault enabled, or SecureBoot, does it have a firmware password? Resetting passwords is nowhere near as simple on a modern Mac running Mojave, or with a T2 chip. https://support.apple.com/HT201573

Answer (score 0):

You informed that Recovery mode works, so it is simple.

- Boot into recovery mode,
- Open Disk Utility on the recovery mode menu.

You will see the encrypted HDD partition is Grayed-Out.

[image]

- Select the encrypted partition
- Click on File menu of disk Utility
- Select **UNLOCK** (*you may have another word translated, but look the picture below for the item location on the file menu.*)
- Type the disk password (Try all the password you said you have)

[image]

- Once you type the correct one, the disk will be unlocked (which means, data is accessible for you)

[image]

---

After successfully unlocking it, close disk utility. You will then return to that initial menu of the recovery mode. You can then click on UTILITY, and open Terminal, once on terminal, the unlocked volume/partition will be mounted under /Volumes

You can `cd /Volumes/<your volume name>` and access all disk data.

Now it is also possible for you to change the user password, and reboot into normal mode to login.